# Form save using ckeditor in asp.net and sql server

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, sql-server

I try to save my form with CKEditor and add autosave function mean all input will autosave:

```
    <script>
    CKEDITOR.replace('Perfil_Descripcion');
</script>

<script>
    $('document').ready(function () {
        $('#preview').hide(); //Default setting
        for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {

            CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement(); //fix texrarea update value

            CKEDITOR.instances[instance].on('key', function () { //save, here comes the error
                $("#btnUpdatePerfil").trigger('click');
            });

        }
    });
    //Save in db
    function CKUpdate() {
        for (instance in CKEDITOR.instances) {

            CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement(); 


            $('#generalform').ajaxForm({ 
                target: '#preview',
                success: function () {
                    $('#preview').show('slow').delay(800).hide('slow');
                }
            });
        }
    }

                            <form id="generalform" method="get" action="?">

                            <h3 class="page-header">Descripcion sobre tu persona</h3>
                                        <div class="row">
                                            <div class="col-sm-12">
                                                <div class="form-group">
                                                    <!--<textarea id="editor" class="form-control"></textarea>-->
                                                    <textarea class="form-control" rows="9" id="Perfil_Descripcion" name="Perfil_Descripcion"></textarea>
                                                    <span id="preview"></span>
                                                </div><!-- /.form-group -->
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                     </form>
```

My problem is :

1. This autosave CKupdate() (refer line -> comment //auto save ) trigger when i put some text, but have bugs, because save it
   sometimes. Im not sure how to fix the bug.
2. After user press save, save function will trigger everytime user
   insert any string inside textarea and after few second my browser
   will hang. I think this on('key', not function well or maybe need to
   change to someting else, like a click function, but also have bugs and sometimes save it.

what im trying to do actually is create textarea with CKEditor then save value into db and create a function to display in the textarea for edit the content.

Another problem is that I have to quickly press the save button.

Comment: if someone knows how to do that, with other wysiwyg, it is also appreciated

Answer (score 1):

This works fine in my case:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor.js"></script>

    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" TextMode="MultiLine"></asp:TextBox>

    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Save" OnClick="Button1_Click" />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        CKEDITOR.replace('<%=TextBox1.ClientID %>');
    </script>
```

For this example to work you have to set `ValidateRequest="false"` in the page directive , otherwise you will get a `"A potentially dangerous Request.Form value was detected from the client"` error.

If you want to use CKeditor without the PostBack functionality and code begind you can do this:

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor.js"></script>

    <textarea rows="9" id="Perfil_Descripcion" name="Perfil_Descripcion"></textarea>

    <input id="Button1" type="button" value="Save" onclick="saveText()" />

     <script type="text/javascript">
         CKEDITOR.replace('Perfil_Descripcion');

         function saveText() {
             //now you have the data from the editor in javascript
             var text = CKEDITOR.instances.Perfil_Descripcion.getData();
             alert(text);
         }
    </script>
```

From this you can also create an autosave, make a javscript function that is called with a `setInterval` and save the text from the editor with `CKEDITOR.instances.Perfil_Descripcion.getData()`

Comment: Now the problem is that I do not always print the textarea when I want to edit , so it is sometimes printed and sometimes not. But great answer.

Comment: someone have any idea that can be?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by printing? You want to send the content of a CKEditor to a physical printer?

Comment: No, no i only want to see in the textarea when i want to edit the saved text, sorry for my bad english

Comment: You can do that by wrapping `CKEDITOR.replace` in a function and call that function with a button. If you don't want a textarea visible at all wrap it in a hidden `<div>` and show it when the same edit button is clicked.

Comment: ok, my fault, i want to do something like this, but isn't work. http://ckeditor.com/forums/Support/CKEditor-with-HTML-content-stores-displays-but-cannot-display-for-edit